# Vich-Uploader error saying to configure db_driver

Tags: php, symfony

```
The child node "db_driver" at path "vich_uploader" must be configured.
```

As you may see, the `vich_uploader` is telling me to configure `db_driver` but every db_driver is configured in vich and in other locations. I'm trying to do a composer update command, then a cache:clear, all end in the same error.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please try to avoid links in questions and answers, because they may go down in the future.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll remove it now

Comment: do you have it like, for example: `vich_uploader: db_driver:  orm`? Note that `db_driver` option under `vich_uploader` is [required](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php#L43). You can also override it under the `mappings`. About overriding it under the `mappings` node, config reference says: `overides the default db driver set above. Allows seperate driver per mapping`.

Comment: Can you upload your config for `vich_uploader`?

Comment: vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    mappings:
            inject_on_load:     false
            delete_on_update:   true
            delete_on_remove:   true
It is without the additional code, it's only the configuration, the rest of the code is too long for the comment